Porque se bloqueo azure?
Tengo una maquina virtual en microsoft azure, pero desde ayer al iniciar sesión me aparece que no tengo acceso a la maquina virtual debajo de mi cuenta aparece restricted tenant, aparece este mensaje al iniciar sesión.
You are not a member of this tenant and do not have access to this directory or any subscriptions/resources within. Your interactions will be limited to directory switching or passthrough scenarios only. Click 'I acknowledge' to continue to as a passthrough user without any access to the directory. You can click 'Sign out' to sign out of this session.
solo hay una cuenta.

